# How to get the dominant colors using Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to get the colors (256/8-bit) used in an image and the number of times they occur. I was hoping to get this through `image.getcolors()` but I don't get how to convert the 8-bit color value to RGB.

```
from PIL import Image

original = Image.open('image.jpg')                   # Open image
reduced = original.convert("P", palette=Image.WEB)   # Convert to WEB palette (216 colors)
color_count = reduced.getcolors()                    # Get list of (count, color)
```

This works fine and I get a list of tuples with the colors in range 0 to 255. How do I get the RGB value of this 8-bit pixel?

Comment: By converting to a palette image you have changed the colours, surely? So you are no longer counting the colours that were originally present.

Comment: @Mark Setchell That is fine since my original image would have had 16 million colors and it wouldn't make sense to count them. This downsampling loses some info but doesn't affect my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL's  `getpalette` method returns the list of RGB values for each color index of the image palette. Unfortunately, all RGB values are concatenated into a single list, so you have to post-process the result (i.e. group values 3 by 3) to get what you need. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image

original = Image.open('test.png') # open RGB image
reduced = original.convert("P", palette=Image.WEB) # convert to web palette (216 colors)
palette = reduced.getpalette() # get palette as [r,g,b,r,g,b,...]
palette = [palette[3*n:3*n+3] for n in range(256)] # group 3 by 3 = [[r,g,b],[r,g,b],...]
color_count = [(n, palette[m]) for n,m in reduced.getcolors()]

print(color_count)
```

Output:

```
[(111230, [1, 1, 1]), (16063, [23, 23, 23]), (7468, [16, 8, 18]),
 (15, [237, 240, 163]), (3, [253, 249, 160]), ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something understandable.  Numerous stumbling blocks using histograms, palette, and getcolors.

```
dictc={}
im = Image.open( "top5toronto.jpg" ).convert( 'RGB' )
for i in range( im.width ):
    for j in range( im.height ) :
        h = im.getpixel( ( i,j ) )
        if h in dictc:
            dictc[h] = dictc[h] + 1
        else:
            dictc[h]=1  
#now sort it by values rather than keys descending      
print(sorted(dictc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) )
im.close()
#returns [((213, 218, 240), 1792), ((213, 217, 242), 550), ((212, 218, 242), 412), ((213, 218, 238), 252), ((215, 217, 240), 142), ((222, 224, 245), 121),
```

Comment: The o.p. said that the goal is to obtain the color histo from an 8bit image. This answer suggests a solution for a 24-bit image which is similar but not exactly the same.